# Calculate the minimum and maximum for a function

Tags: java, function, max, min

I am looking for a way of calculating the minimum and maximum values for a function in Java. The program I am looking to create would see all the local minimums and maximums for a function which oscillates around the x-axis (This is not a school assignment, although I have mentioned cos(x) in the outline below). The methods that I have seen across the internet all calculate the min/max value for an array. I am looking into writing a method that will directly calculate this value for a function which goes from x = 0 to x = infinity.

For example, cos(x) from x = 0 to x = 5000. There are tons of local minimums and maximums,

Also, sin(x) from x = 0 to x = 5000. A large amount of local maximums and minimums to be found.

The function is also continuous from x = 0 to x = infinity.

Is there a preferred numerical method for doing this?

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
         Function testFunction = new Function()
         {
             public double f(double x) {
             return something;
         }

       }

         findMax(testFunction, 1, 40000, 0.001);
         findMin(testFunction, 1, 40000, 0.001);

    }

    public static interface Function {
        public double f(double x);
    }

    public static double function(double x) {
        return Math.cos(x);
    }

    public static void findMax(Function f, double lowerBound, double upperBound, double step) {

    }

    public static void findMin(Function f, double lowerBound, double upperBound, double step) {

    }

}
```

This is a similar program which finds roots -

```
// Finds the roots of the specified function passed in with a lower bound,
    // upper bound, and step size.
    public static void findRoots(Function f, double lowerBound,
                  double upperBound, double step) {
    double x = lowerBound, next_x = x;
    double y = f.f(x), next_y = y;
    int s = sign(y), next_s = s;

    for (x = lowerBound; x <= upperBound ; x += step) {
        s = sign(y = f.f(x));
        if (s == 0) {
        System.out.println(x);
        } else if (s != next_s) {
        double dx = x - next_x;
        double dy = y - next_y;
        double cx = x - dx * (y / dy);
        System.out.println(cx);
        }
        next_x = x; next_y = y; next_s = s;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Good point, I probably shouldn't have wrote the post at midnight. I will update it ....

Comment: Derivate your quadratic function and test extremes ?

Comment: @Axion004, do you know how mathematically find the min max of any second degree equation? Have you ever hard about first and second order derivative?

Comment: How will you know when you have reached a maximum in the case of a function like `f(x) = x^2 + x`?  To find the max/min on a closed domain, you can use your current approach, namely dividing the domain on a fine grid and testing all the values.

Comment: You are looking for mathematical optimization methods - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_optimization This question is way too broad to answer though. You haven't even said if you functions are continuous.

Comment: My mistake, the function is continuous. Reviewing answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the most naive implementation of your `findMax()` function:

```
public static void findMax(Function f, double lowerBound, double upperBound, double step) {
    double maxValue = f.f(lowerBound);

    for (double i=lowerBound; i <= upperBound; i+=step) {
        double currEval = f.f(i);
        if (currEval > maxValue) {
            maxValue = currEval;
        }
    }

    return maxValue;
}
```

You can play around with the step size until you converge on a maximum value.  The smaller the step size, the finer resolution you will have to detect a maximum.

The next step over this implementation would be to consider diving the grid containing `lowerBound` and `upperBound` *unevenly*.  For example, in the case of `cos(x)`, you don't need to sample very much near the minima and maxima because the function doesn't change value very much there.  On the other hand, near where it crosses zero the function changes value extremely fast.  So an improvement on what I wrote here would be to design your grid to be more dynamic (and therefore requiring fewer evaluations).

Comment: @Axion004 Please review this answer.

Comment: Thank You, reviewing and testing.

Comment: I apologize, I now realize that I need to write a new question. I will make a new question. It would be much more efficient to make one method which looks directly at the value of the derivative. When the derivative is within a certain epsilon, say eps = 0.000001, then this value is returned. This would go through an interval of [a:b] and then return all values in which a minimum or maximum occurred. I apologize for not seeing this earlier.

Comment: The first derivative will only give you a local minimum or maximum.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for all local minimums and maximums (not global max/min). This may sound sort of strange, the method is designed to find all of the local max/min inside the interval of [a:b].

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this will help but could this be what your looking for. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/The_Science_of_Programming/Peaks_and_Valleys

Comment: Please dont just post links as answer. Give also a quick summary what the links is about and how it could help to solve the problem.